# Why data is getting undefined on the server side coming from client side ? (reactjs to nodejs)

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am trying to send the data as parameters in `GET` route. But on server side when I am checking its `undefined`. What I am doing wrong?

**Below is the `React` code:**

**P.S.: Here process.env.REACT_APP_API = localhost:5000/api**

```
const App = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    page: 0,
    search: "",
    username: "Hey Baby!",
    typingTimeout: 0,
    load: true,
    filter: ["search", "story", 0],
    result: 0,
    processTime: 0
  });

const { page, search, username, typingTimeout, load, filter, result, processTime } = state;

const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

const fetchPosts = () => {

       alert(filter); //Here I am getting the filter **array** values successfully

        axios
            .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/posts`,
 { page, search, username, typingTimeout, load, filter, result, processTime })
            .then(response => {
                 console.log(response.data.datas);
                setPosts(response.data.datas);
            })
            .catch(error => alert(error));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts();
    }, []);

return (
----------html code------
)

}
```

**Below is the `Node Controller/Route` code:**

```
router.get('/posts', list);  //route

exports.list = async(req, res) => {  //controller

  const {  page, search, username, typingTimeout, load, filter, result, processTime } = req.body;
  console.log("filter = " +  filter);

  console.log("page = " + page);

  await Axios.get(
     `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/${f1}?query=&tags=${f2}&page=${page}&numericFilters=created_at_i>0`
     )
     .then((r) => {
       console.log(r.data.hits);
       res.send({ datas: r.data.hits });
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log("err = "+ err);
     });
};
```

This is what I am getting into the `console` in `nodejs` side:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
GET /api/posts - - ms - -
filter = undefined
page = undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Node Controller/Route f1 and f2 are not defined. Get API does not have req.body you should you req.query

```
const {  page, search, username, typingTimeout, load, filter, result, processTime } = req.query;
```

You should pass as params, check npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```
axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/posts`,
    {
        params: {
            page,
            search,
            username,
            typingTimeout,
            load,
            filter,
            result,
            processTime
        }
    }
)
```